# Convert String to Double

Tags: c#

How can I convert a number held by a string into a double?

Comment: Simple questions like these are easily answered by using Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "safe" way:

```
string number = "9";

double result;
if(!double.TryParse(number, out result))
{
    // conversion failed, string is not a valid double/number
}
```

or the "optimistic" way:

```
Convert.ToDouble(number);
```

Comment: I don't know why I had so much trouble with this.  Brain lock, I guess.  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your safest bet is to use [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)